# Javascript - bind() before ECMAScript 5 / how to simulate with apply() or call()?

Tags: javascript, binding, this, ecmascript-5

Just ran into a binding problem that's right on the edge of my Javascript universe, so I'm going to talk my way through it, as Regis recommends, and arrive at my question:

```
function foo() {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", this.bar);
}

foo.prototype.bar = function(evt) {
    alert(this);
}

test = new foo();
```

This alerts with the `document.body` element, since the `this` is lost due to the function reference.  So, the reference must use `bind()` to persist the reference:

```
function foo() {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", this.bar.bind(this));
}
```

This alerts with the expected object of type `foo`.

---

But, according to [this table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), a pile of browsers won't play nice if I use `bind()`.  I've been reading up on `apply()` and `call()` but they seem to be applicable for cases with arguments.  How can I achieve a the `bind()` behavior I need in this situation, using pre-ECMAScript5 methods?

Comment: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ (Click on "Our Goal" then hit next.  You will see the answer there.)  Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

Comment: Cool beans man - very helpful.  Happy to accept as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving my own answer, John Resig [tells you how here](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/).  (Click on **1) Our Goal** then hit **Next**).

Resig's solution is from prototype.js. You can also see MDN's description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) with implementation code as well, approximating the actual ES5 implementation.  It should be good enough for most purposes, though.